# How to set UIImage from nomal state and title text in the selected state in UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

How I can set UIImage in the normal state and set title in the selected state in my UIButton?

Hi, I try to set a UIImage in the normal state of UIButton, but when  set an UImage in normal state this change the title of UIButton in the selected state changing the title for the image . I am using

`myButton setTitle:content forState:UIControlStateSelected`

in the state selected.

How I can set UIImage in the normal state and set title in the selected state in my UIButton?

PDT: sorry for my english!.

Comment: if you add from xib you get option there only

Comment: So here you want to set image for normal state and only title(no image) for selected?

Comment: use button tag to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with this code:

```
[myButton setTitle:content forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[myButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[myButton setImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: @kakashy: With Pleasure :)

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

BOOL selected;

```
-(IBAction)btnClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
    if(selected)
    {
        [chkBtn setTitle:@"selected" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        chkImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@" "]; 
        NSLog(@"%@",chkBtn.titleLabel);
        selected=NO;
    }
    else
    {
        [chkBtn setTitle:@" " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        chkImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_minus_pink.png"]; 
        selected=YES;
     }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

// set with `UIColor`

```
[self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

// set with `UIImage`

```
[self.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BlackRightBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For `Button Selected`

```
if (self.button.isSelected == YES)
{
    [self.button setTitle:@"Your_ButtonTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define button and `setImage` for normal and selected state. Like this way.

```
buttonJobs = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom ];
buttonJobs.tag = 1;
[buttonJobs setTitle:@"Jobs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


buttonJobs.frame = CGRectMake(2, 56, 109, 33);
[buttonJobs setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabButtonImage_Off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//buttonJobs.png

[buttonJobs setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabButtonImage_On.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

[buttonJobs addTarget:self action:@selector(btnNextTab:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And in button selector method you can set your button selected according `sender's tag`.

```
-(void)btnNextTab:(UIButton*)sender
{

  if(sender.tag == 1)
  {
      sender.selected = YES;
  }

}
```

And for Title you can change color of text.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Ok, but if I won't to set UIImage only in the state selected but I want to set only Title (text) in the state selected? how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

add your code like this:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"Your String" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

where img.png should  not be there in your bundle

you can set this through Interface Builder as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"Your String" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[myButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```